# tableview in swift ios detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm creating a Todo app with swift for iPhone. I want the tableview to show the name and the time of the task in a tableview. the Textlabel shows the correct name of the task but the detailTextLabel shows just Detail and not the time.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {      
   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell!   
    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]        

    if task.done {

        cell?.textLabel!.text = "‼️\(task.name!)"
        task.time = cell!.detailTextLabel!.text
    } else {            
        cell?.textLabel!.text = "\(task.name!)"
        task.time = cell!.detailTextLabel!.text
    }        
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment of the detailTextLabel is backwards.

```
if task.done {

    cell?.textLabel!.text = "‼️\(task.name!)"
    cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = task.time
}
else {

    cell?.textLabel!.text = "\(task.name!)"
    cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = task.time

}
```

Comment: No problem!  Please mark as answer if it resolved it. (Which it did ;)

Answer (score 0):

You never actually set the detail label text to anything. You'll need to set it with something like this:

`cell?.detailTextLabel!.text = task.time.longStyleDateString`

And here's that Date extension:

`extension Date {
        var longStyleDateString: String {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .long
            return formatter.string(from: self)
        }
    }`